# Swift coding issue: Type '_ErrorCodeProtocol' has no member 'success'

Tags: swift, debugging, swiftui, error-handling, type-inference

I'm currently working on a Swift project and I'm encountering some issues with my code. I'm seeking assistance from the community to help me resolve these problems. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Problem:**
I have a ContentView.swift file where I'm getting the following errors:

- Type '_ErrorCodeProtocol' has no member 'success'
- Expression pattern of type '(_) -> SudokuGrid' cannot match values of type 'SudokuGrid'

```
class NumberGenerator {
    typealias SudokuGridCompletion = (Result<SudokuGrid, Error>) -> Void

    func generateSudokuGrid(completion: @escaping SudokuGridCompletion) {
        // Your logic for generating the Sudoku grid

        // Simulating a successful result
        let sudokuGrid = SudokuGrid(grid: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
        completion(.success(sudokuGrid))

        // Simulating a failure result
        // let error = NSError(domain: "com.example", code: 123, userInfo: nil)
        // completion(.failure(error))
    }
}

struct SudokuGrid {
    var grid: [[Int]]
}

// Usage example
let numberGenerator = NumberGenerator()
numberGenerator.generateSudokuGrid { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let sudokuGrid):
        print("Generated Sudoku grid: \(sudokuGrid.grid)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error generating Sudoku grid: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I've checked the import statements and verified the spelling and capitalization of the types. I've also made sure that the types are defined in the correct scope. However, the errors persist.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance to help me resolve these issues. If you've encountered similar problems or have expertise in Swift programming, your assistance would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please show a [mcve], including but not limited to the signature of `numberGenerator.generateSudokuGrid`.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated the post to include a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE) that focuses on the signature of the numberGenerator.generateSudokuGrid method.

Comment: Your example isn't actually reproducible. [See it working exactly as expected here](https://swiftfiddle.com/au7dyywpqndends6jpdzreszve).

Comment: You have errors in your view but you haven’t posted the view code.